# Proper vectorial subspaces from $\mathbb{R}^{n}$

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

> Let $E\subset \mathbb{R}^{n}$ a vectorial subspace such that $E\neq \mathbb{R}^{n}$. Show that, $E$ is a connected set.

Does anyone have any ideas?

Comment: Show it's path-connected. For example, find a line between the points, parameterised by $t$, and note that such a function is continuous.

Comment: Don't really need to assume $E \neq \mathbb{R}^n$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider two arbitrary points in $E$, namely $a,b$. Consider the continuous function :

$$ f:[0,1] \rightarrow E $$

defined by $f(t)=(1-t)a+tb$. Clearly $f(t) \in E$ because $E$ is a vectorial space so $f$ is a path in $E$ such that $f(0)=a, f(1)=b$. Then $E$ is a path-connected set so connected set.